# Objective C Predicate of an array using a range of numbers

Tags: objective-c, numbers, integer, range, nspredicate

So I have an nspredicate that I am using to filter values in a json array. Instead of just searching for one value, I would like the predicate to find objects that are within a range of numbers such as 0-1.0 or 1.1-2.0.

This is my current predicate:

```
NSPredicate *Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Engine CONTAINS %@", @"?"];
```

It is probably a simple solution but I have yet to find an answer to this.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html

You can use conditions like `AND` and `OR` as well as inequality operations `<` and `>`

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do this and the docs have a few examples - see the [Basic Comparisons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215832) section.

A basic solution would probably look like this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Engine BETWEEN %@", @[ @0, @1]];
```